# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency when function call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am struggling due to waring from eslint.

Below is sample code and once I run the below code, I get the waringing from eslint.

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'maxId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

How can I remove the warining?

I want to make the process to call the loadMapData function only when pageNo and StartDate are changed.

Sample Code;

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const VehicleHistory = (props) => {
  //console.log("VehicleHistory");
  
  const pageSize = 10;

  const [mapData, setMapData] = useState();
  const [pageNo, setpageNo] = useState(1);
  const [startDate, setstartDate] = useState(100);
  const [maxId, setmaxId] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect.pageNo chainging====");

    
  const loadMapData = async () => {
    console.log('call loadMapData====');  
    try {
        //Api call to get list data
        //No meaning. Just for testing
        const _pageNo = pageNo;
        const _pageSize = pageSize
        const _maxId = maxId;
        setMapData('test'+_pageNo + _pageSize+_maxId);
        setmaxId(_pageNo + _pageSize);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
    }
  }

  
    loadMapData();
  }, [pageNo]);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect.startDate chainging====");
    setMapData(null);
    setpageNo(1);

  }, [startDate]);




  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={e => setpageNo(p => p + 1)}>Change page</button>
      <button onClick={e => setstartDate(s => s + 1)}>Change date</button>
      
      <br />pageNo : {pageNo}
      <br />startdate : {startDate}
      <br />mapdata : {mapData}
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default VehicleHistory;
```

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: put `maxId` as  dependancy `....}, [pageNo, maxId]);
` otherwise `maxId` inside the effect may not be get changed, check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP-NrbQHFww&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwisvxhZ135pogtX7_Oe3Q3A&index=11

Comment: @Niyas Nazar Thanks. great help to me

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here in this code. Basically inside `useEffect` you are expecting `maxId`. you need to understand how `useEffect`  work. `useEffect` required array of dependency which ensure it will run whenever these value changes. So in your case `maxId` is changing. And `useEffect` is not sure what to that's why eslint giving error.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect.pageNo chainging====");

    
  const loadMapData = async () => {
    console.log('call loadMapData====');  
    try {
        //Api call to get list data
        //No meaning. Just for testing
        const _pageNo = pageNo;
        const _pageSize = pageSize
        const _maxId = maxId; <- Issue is here
        setMapData('test'+_pageNo + _pageSize+_maxId);
        setmaxId(_pageNo + _pageSize);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
    }
  }

  
    loadMapData();
  }, [pageNo]);
```

Solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
...code
},[pageNo,maxId]) <- add maxId in dependency array
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
But when I added the maxId at the dependancy array, the function was called twice.
Isn't there any way to call the function just once?

Comment: You need then some kind of previous hook value. If both(in your case `maxId`) are same do not call function. Its like `componentDidUpdate` . Here is the reference: https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/

Comment: Anytime :-) .  If this help you mark this answer as accept and upvote it. So that in future someone stuck on same problem this question popup (this is how stackoverflow algorithm work :-\)